# Wordpress custom taxonomy term description html tags

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've looked all over stack overflow and the WP forums and can't find anything from within the last few years that works for this issue.

I've created a custom taxonomy(album category) for a custom post type(album) and I need to display the taxonomy description as html paragraphs, but it just outputs as raw text(which is how it is saved in the database - no html tags at all).

I've tried adding `remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data' );` to the functions file, but that does nothing even after re-activating the theme and updating the descriptions.

I could just add a custom field to the taxonomy, but it would be nice to use the existing description field if I could just get it to use html tags.

Answer (score 3):

I am not even qualified enough to be a neophyte, but I did find the following online, and it seems to work and so far not crash my site.  No warranties, implied or otherwise.  I just feel like I should contribute, given all the help this site has been to me.

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'pre_link_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'pre_link_notes', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data' );
```

I also think the taxonomy descriptions are generally an underutilized feature, and whatever hacks are available may one day be made into features.  I look forward to the downvotes!

Comment: Straight copy/paste to my theme, and it appears to be working as expected; WordPress now allows me to save html to the field.

Answer (score 1):

delete html tags with **strip_tags()**

functions.php

```
function my_custom_single_title() {
    if ( is_tax( array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ) ) && 0 === absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ) {
        $description = wc_format_content( term_description() );
        if ( $description ) {
            echo '<h1>' . strip_tags($description) . '</h1>';
        }
    }
}
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'my_custom_single_title', 10 );
```